# How to connect JobTracker in EMR cluster

Tags: hadoop, ssh, emr

I am using Elastic MapReduce cluster. I try to connect web interfaces like job tracker, task tracker by following the link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-ssh-tunnel.html
I am using putty but, I can't connect to master-public-dns:9100 by getting time out error.

How can I connect to those interfaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your proxy enabled ?
After your query , I followed the instructions for macosx and was able to get it working.

My foxyproxy plugin in firefox looks like the following

[image]

Kindly share the screenshot of your foxyproxy setting as well.
My looks like the following (removing the configurations related to ip starting with 10*)

[image]

Comment: thanks for your helps.. It was because of the changing port numbers between amazon versions.